# Programmatically setting Outlook offline mode within Add-in Express developed in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, addin-express

I'm developing an add-in for Outlook using C# and Add-in Express. I wonder if is possible to set Outlook to work offline programmatically from the add-in itself. Looking for a solution i've found only a way to know programmatically if Outlook is set in offline mode or not.
I would accept a solution that use only Outlook VSTO add-in as well if is not possible to solve this problem using only add-in express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-in Express (nor VSTO) doesn't provide anything for that. Also the Outlook Object Model doesn't let you do this - the `Namespace.Offline` property is read-only. It looks like Redemption allows setting up their `RDOSession.Offline` property. Be aware, the `Offline` property returns valid information only for an Exchange profile. It is not intended for non-Exchange account types such as POP3, IMAPI, and HTTP.

Don't forget that users may click the `Work Offline` button on the ribbon which also changes the `Offline` property of the Namespace class. So, from your add-in you can execute the ribbon command programmatically by using the [CommandBars.ExecuteMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso) method which executes the control identified by the idMso parameter. This method is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in `buttons`, `toggleButtons`, and `splitButtons`. The required `idMso` value of the control is `ToggleOnline`. For example, your code might look like that:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("ToggleOnline");
```